# Zend framework 2 module creation

Tags: module, frameworks, zend-framework2

I encountered a problem while trying create a new module:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (Page) could not be initialized.' in /home/sc/projects/zf2/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:175 
 Stack trace: 
 #0 /home/sc/projects/zf2/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php(149): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) 
 #1 /home/sc/projects/zf2/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php(90): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModule('Page') 
 #2 [internal function]: Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->onLoadModules(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) 
 #3 /home/sc/projects/zf2/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) 
 #4 /home/sc/projects/zf2/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\Event in /home/sc/projects/zf2/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php on line 175
```

Does anybody knows what should i do with this?

Comment: Can you post the code for your Module.php file from the Page module?

Comment: namespace Page;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}

Comment: Sorry im using stackoverflow for the first time and i dont know how to format my code correct.

Comment: sorry cant format my code correct)